# PHP Array Select Random Value on Refresh

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, random

I have Submit button on Page. Once I click each time it should give random different result.

I have below array code

```
$qty = 10;
$array = array(4 => 2, 6 => 5, 7 => 10, 8 => 1, 10 => 5);
$array = arsort($array);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
//array_rand($array);
exit;
```

Array pair is Customer & It's Quantity. I need to compare `$qty` with array's highest value. If it matches then take that value out & print out final result.

It is not necessary to assign 100% qty to each customer. But in the end 10 qty should assign overall.

So output can be

1st Click on Submit Button

```
Array
(
    [7] => 10
)
```

2nd Click on Submit Button

```
Array
(
    [7] => 2
    [6] => 2
    [10] => 2
    [4] => 2
    [8] => 2
)
```

3rd Click on Submit Button

```
Array
(
    [7] => 5
    [6] => 2
    [10] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added inline comments that might help you to get:

[Demo here](https://eval.in/764260)

```
<?php
$qty   = 10;
$array = array(4 => 2, 6 => 5, 7 => 10, 8 => 1, 10 => 5);

$final_array = [];

while ($qty > 0) {
    $rand_index = array_rand($array);  // Get random customer
    $max_val    = $array[$rand_index]; // Get the maximum qty available for the customer

    if (!$max_val) {
        continue;
    }

    if ($max_val > $qty) {
        $max_val = $qty;
    }

    $possible_val = rand(1, $max_val); // Assign random qty to the customer but not more than allowed

    // Check if customer is added with qty already, if not add
    if (array_key_exists($rand_index, $final_array)) {
        $final_array[$rand_index] += $possible_val;
    } else {
        $final_array[$rand_index] = $possible_val;
    }

    $array[$rand_index] -= $possible_val;
    $qty -= $possible_val;
}

print_r($final_array); // Your final desired combination
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Customer who has Max Qty should get Priority that is missing

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function random_int() `

Comment: It is for PHP 7, you can replace it with `rand()`. Updated the answer as well

Comment: Ok got it Thanks 2 things 1] Customer who has Max Qty should get Priority that is missing can you look in to that? 2] If  array(4 => 2, 6 => 5); then it goes to infinite loop